# How to add objects to an NSArray using for loop?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsarray

I want to add the `[NSDecimalNumber numberWithInt:i]` to an array using for loop.

It is hardcoded :

```
 NSArray *customTickLocations = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: [NSDecimalNumber numberWithInt:1],[NSDecimalNumber numberWithInt:2],[NSDecimalNumber numberWithInt:3],[NSDecimalNumber numberWithInt:4],[NSDecimalNumber numberWithInt:5],[NSDecimalNumber numberWithInt:6],[NSDecimalNumber numberWithInt:7],[NSDecimalNumber numberWithInt:8],[NSDecimalNumber numberWithInt:9],[NSDecimalNumber numberWithInt:10],[NSDecimalNumber numberWithInt:11],[NSDecimalNumber numberWithInt:12],nil];
```

I want like this, but I can add only one object here....

```
for (int i=0; i<totalImagesOnXaxis; i++)
{
    customTickLocations = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSDecimalNumber numberWithInt:i]];
}
```

Please help me out of this,
Thanks in Advance,
Madan

Comment: Why do you need the array anyway? Looks like the value in the array at index `i` is always `i`.

Answer (score 46):

*NSArray* is ***immutable***. Use the mutable version, ***NSMutableArray***.

Answer (score 22):

```
NSMutableArray * customTickLocations = [NSMutableArray new];
for (int idx = 0; idx < 12; ++idx) {
    [customTickLocations addObject:[NSDecimalNumber numberWithInt:idx]];
}

...
```

Answer (score 10):

you cannot add Objects at run time to NSArray.For adding or removing objects at Run time you have to use NSMutableArray.

```
NSMutableArray *mutableArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
    [mutableArray addObject:[NSDecimalNumber numberWithInt:i]];
}
```

Answer (score 7):

```
NSMutableArray *customTickLocations = [NSMutableArray array];
for (int i=0; i<totalImagesOnXaxis; i++)
{
    [customTickLocations addObject:[NSDecimalNumber numberWithInt:i]];
}
```

The NSMutableArray class declares the programmatic interface to objects that manage a modifiable array of objects. This class adds insertion and deletion operations to the basic array-handling behavior inherited from NSArray

[NSMutableArray Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 5):

```
NSMutableArray *customTickLocations = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for(int i = 0; i<WhateverNoYouWant;i++)
{
  NSDecimalNumber * x = [NSDecimalNumber numberWithInt:i]
  [customTickLocations addObject:x]
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I found that using this technique is a great way to easily add a few more elements to an NSArray, this was the answer I was looking for when I came to this thread so am posting it as it is a great easy addition.

If I want to add a new array to my current array

```
currentArray = [currentArray arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray: newArray];
```

Answer (score 1):

`NSArray` add object like this:

```
NSArray *arr = @["1","2","3","4"];
```

I think `NSArray` can not `addObject` like `NSMutableArray`. You should try it:

```
NSMutableArray *mulArr = [NSMutableArray new];
[mulArr addObject:[NSDecimalNumber numberWithInt:number]];
```